Mailchimp API deauthorize
I am working on implementing the Mailchimp marketing APIs into my system. I’m working through the authorization component first and don’t see a way for a user to deauthorize once authorized. Is there an API endpoint that allows a user to deauthorize the app they previously authorized?
